# Axios post request sending file , but flask Request.File is empty

Tags: javascript, axios

so im currently working on a react-flask app , and i have a problem , my request.files is empty in flask , i did everything and its not working

I added the name attribute to the file input

```js
<form onSubmit={(e) => handleUploadImage(e)} >
        <div>
          <input type="file" name='file'  
          onChange={(e) => { setImg_obj(e.target.files[0] ); console.log(e.target.files[0])
          }} />
        </div>

        <br />
        <div>
          <button type="submit" >Upload</button>
        </div>
        {/* <img  alt="img" /> */}
      </form>
```

i did create a FormData object and add a multipart/form-data header to teh axios request

```js
const handleUploadImage = async(ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();

    const filou = new FormData();
    filou.append('file', img_obj);

    try {

      console.log(img_obj)

      const response = await axios({
        method: "POST",
        url:"http://127.0.0.1:5000/upload",
        headers: { "content-type": "multipart/form-data" },
        data: {
          data: filou,
        },
        
      })
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    
  }
```

and here my backend

```py
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def fileUpload():
    print("hello")
    
    print(request.form['data'])
    
    # check if the post request has the file part
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        print("no file")
        flash('No file part')
        return "redirect(request.url)"
    file = request.files['file']
    
    # If the user does not select a file, the browser submits an
    # empty file without a filename.
    if file.filename == '':
        print("no selected file")
        flash('No selected file')
        return redirect(request.url)
    
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        print("YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEYYYY")
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        return "redirect(url_for('download_file', name=filename))"
    
    ye = "yeet"
    
    return ye
```

and the result in falsk backend is :

[Python consol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p55YW.png)

while in the front :

[React consol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9kRD.png)

**NOTE : when i do the request with thunderclient it works.**

**Links : Full code here if u want to :https://github.com/LyesYe/Photo-Restoration-Project**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing the `filou` object as the data key, you should pass it directly as the data option in the `axios` request:

```
  const handleUploadImage = async(ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();

    const filou = new FormData();
    filou.append('file', img_obj);

    try {
      console.log(img_obj)

      const response = await axios({
        method: "POST",
        url:"http://127.0.0.1:5000/upload",
        headers: { "content-type": "multipart/form-data" },
        data: filou, // Try this line
      })
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }  
  }
```

Comment: MAN .... Life saver , appreciate your help , indeed the problem was there

Comment: You're welcome, I once had the same problem with axios while sending a multipart to a java backend